¿ Como declarar el uso de un metodo de un dll en un procedimiento de visual basic?
Estoy  profundizando mas en visual basic y tratando de comprender la sentencia "DECLARE". Lo que he entendido es que te ayuda a referenciar un archivo externo dll para poder usar sus funciones o metodos.
El archivo dll ya lo tengo creado (LIB_TEST.dll) y vinculado al proyecto correctamente.
Proyecto dll vinculado

Dll creado automaticamente al depurar proyecto principal

Este es el codigo dentro del DLL:
Public Class LIBRERIA
Public Sub MYSUB()
    Console.WriteLine("PROBANDO LIBRERIA")
End Sub
End Class

Este es el  metodo que deberia invocar y ejecutar el dll usando el DECLARE
 Declare Sub MYSUB Lib "LIB_TEST.dll" ()
 Sub InvocarExterno()
 MYSUB()
 End Sub

El hecho es que al ejecutar el metodo InvocarExterno() me esta devolviendo el siguiente error :

Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException'
en VisualBasic.dll Unable to find an entry point named 'MYSUB' in DLL
'LIB_TEST.dll'.

Quiero resaltar que si esta encontrando el dll correctamente, lo que no esta reconociendo es el nombre del metodo MYSUB ni usando el ALIAS.
Soy conciente que probablemente existan otros metodos para invocar dll o este metodo puede estar desfasado , pero mi intencion tratar de seguir la documentacion de la guia de visual basic de microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/declare-statement
Saludos.

Que yo sepa, Declare es similar al DllImport de C# y se usa para llamar funciones escritas en C. Según recuerdo en C# no necesitas hacer ningún import si agregas otro proyecto de C# como dependencia. Tal vez pase algo similar con VB, que estás utilizando Declare para un DLL no escrito en C.

La libreria esta escrita en VB al igual que el proyecto. Puede que tengas razon y solo pueda importar funciones en C.,aunque la documentacion no indica nada de ello.
